# React-Native display user input in textboxes

Tags: android, react-native, redux

I am pretty new to react native and not sure how to handle my approach here. I have this screen.
[image: PlayScreen]

I want to enter points and when I click on plus or minus I want to have a record of these points in the view above. 
What is the best way to handle this? I thought about making an array of textboxes and push them in every time I hit a button but I don't know where to store the array without global scope. Or I save everything in Redux but I think it doesn't make sense to put everything into Redux.
Would be happy about a suggestions, thanks :)

Project is on github: https://github.com/AlessandroVol23/Counter10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if my idea can be helpful.

If I understood what you mean, you would like to store points that you're introducing when you click the + button and show them in the view. Also, my question is: Would you also like to show the points every time you go back to this view?

If so, my approach would be:

Storing points in an array and then save it in the redux store (This will allow you to show your points when you visit this view again)

const numbers = [40, 30, 50, 99]

Then inside the component, you only need to go through this array with a map and show the list. Something like:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> This comes from the redux store
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li>{number}</li>
);
```

listItems will contain a list of number that you can then render inside the component.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just the idea is sometimes missing. Thanks! :)